# Requests.get in multiprocessing pool blocked by a Matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

See the code example below.  The symptom is that the `requests.get(url)` within a `multiprocessing` `Pool` seems to be somehow blocked by a `matplotlib` `figure()`.

The ingredients needed to reproduce this rather unexpected behavior are:

1. Use the `multiprocessing` `Pool` to apply a function to a list; a plain `request.get(url)` after `plt.figure()` runs fluently.
2. The function for the `Pool` `map` contains `requests.get`; using other "simpler" function such as the identity function (e.g. `f` in the code sample) runs fluently.
3. Before starting the Pool, create a matplotlib `figure`; without this `figure`, the code runs fluently.

Code example:

```
# matplotlib.__version__: 1.4.3
# requests.__version__: 2.9.1
# Python version:
#   2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17)
#   [GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]
# uname -a:
#   Darwin myMBP 16.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.4.0:
#   Thu Dec 22 22:53:21 PST 2016;
#   root:xnu-3789.41.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookPro11,3 Darwin


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests

urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com']

# Runs as expected:
p = Pool(processes=1)
print 1, p.map(requests.get, urls)

# Runs as expected:
def f(x):
    return x
fig = plt.figure()
p = Pool(processes=1)
print 2, p.map(f, urls)

# Will not run (the p.map takes forever to run):
fig = plt.figure()
p = Pool(processes=1)
print 3, p.map(requests.get, urls)

# REPLACING the previous block with the following
# will again runs as expected:
fig = plt.figure()
print 4, requests.get(urls[0])
```

Output of the code sample:

```
1 [<Response [200]>]
2 ['http://stackoverflow.com']
3
```

Comment: It worked here with Python 2.7.9, matplotlib 1.4.2, and requests 2.4.3.

Comment: @J.P.Petersen I tried your versions with `conda env`; still does not work...

Comment: 1. If this is a new project, python 3.6 is recommended over python 2.7;  2. for running concurrent HTTP requests, `threading` is preferred over `multiprocessing`; 3. Use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (built in in python3, or `pip install futures` in python 2) for [easier concurrency](http://pythonhosted.org/futures/#threadpoolexecutor-example) in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in windows, you will need to move all your code below `def f()` into a:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

block.

Comment: I am using macOS 10.12.3

Comment: I'm having the same issue on macOS 10.12.3, python 3.5.1. It works fine on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You will probably need to open a bug on matplotlib's bug tracker